# Como faço pra descobrir a versão atual do codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Como é que posso para fazer para descobrir a versão atual do Codeigniter via código?

Existe alguma constante ou função que faça isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta usar o [define *built in*](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html?highlight=ci_version):

```
define('CI_VERSION', '2.2.3');
```

Que na versão 3 é definido como

```
const CI_VERSION = '3.2.0-dev';
```

Isto fica em `/system/core/CodeIgniter.php`

Answer (score 3):

Use: `echo CI_VERSION;`. Esta constante está definida em `system/core/CodeIgniter.php`.

[Fonte](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html?highlight=ci_version)